# Substituir valores dentro de string

Tags: c++, string, regex

Como faço para substituir valores dentro de uma *string*?

A *string* será algo como:

```
gabriel = 1.73,derp = 1.80,
```

Leve em conta que essa estrutura é de: `nome = altura, nome = altura,`.

No caso, eu quero substituir a altura de gabriel por 1.75, mas não sei mexer com patterns em c++.

Gostaria de buscar algo como 'gabriel = (%d+)' e substituir por 'gabriel = 1.75'.

O tamanho do nome pode ser maior ou menor.

A altura pode ter mais números e outros valores.

Em Lua seria assim:

```
local str = "gabriel = 1.73, derp = 1.80,"
local size = string.match(str, 'gabriel = (.-),')
print(str)
str = string.gsub(str, 'gabriel = '..size..',', 'gabriel = 1.75,')
print(str)
```

Veja [funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/uyHAul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após a edição vi que o problema era outro. Lua e C++ têm um padrão - com o perdão do trocadilho sem intenção - de padrões de expressões regulares diferente. É necessário fazer uma "tradução". E obviamente as função são ligeiramente diferentes. Ficaria assim:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string texto = "gabriel = 1.73,derp = 1.80,";
    regex padrao("gabriel = (.*?),");
    cout << regex_replace(texto, padrao, "gabriel = 1.75,");
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Dklr6V). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ReplaceSring). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/ReplaceString.cpp).

Eu não gosto de usar RegEx e faria de outra forma, até porque este padrão é muito simples mas está aí como você deseja.

---

Acho que é esta função que você deseja:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    return true;
}

int main() {
    string texto = "gabriel = 1.73,derp = 1.80,";
    replace(texto, "1.73", "1.75");
    cout << texto;
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/sVU9e5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ReplaceString2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/ReplaceString2.cpp).

Comment: O valor pode ser diferente de 1.73, por isso quero saber como usar patterns(acho que é isso), em c++.

Comment: Então coloque em Lua um código que faça o que você quer, o que você colocou não faz.

Comment: Pronto, agora está certo.

Answer (score 3):

Neste código, há a possibilidade de o usuário inserir a string a ser procurada na frase padrão (conteúdo da variável string sWord) e o usuário também pode inserir o valor da altura a ser substituído.

Segue abaixo o código para esta aplicação:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sNum1;
    string sWord = "Este texto contem gabriel = 1.73,derp = 1.80, essa foi uma busca.";
    string nomeProcurado;
    int iPosInicial, iTam;

    cout << "\nTexto Inicial: " << sWord << "\n";

    cout << "\nString a ser procurada: ";
    cin >> nomeProcurado;
    iPosInicial = sWord.find(nomeProcurado);

    cout << "Digite o novo valor: ";
    cin >> sNum1;

    iTam = nomeProcurado.length();

    sWord.replace(iPosInicial+iTam+3,4, sNum1);

    cout << "\nTexto Alterado: " << sWord << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: http://ideone.com/33t4NA